# Flux.error return 200 http code even if exception is thrown

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I work on a project with spring-boot (v2 M3) and spring-webflux.
While coding a feature, I see that my microservice returns me an Http 200 status code while returning an error in a flux.

So, I make a simple test :
I create a simple controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class TestController {

   @GetMapping(value = "/errors")
   public Flux<Object> getErrors() {
       return Flux.error(new RuntimeException("test"));
   }
}
```

With a simple exception handler :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class TestExceptionHandler {

     private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestExceptionHandler.class);

     @ExceptionHandler(value = { RuntimeException.class })
     public ResponseEntity<String> handleServerError(final RuntimeException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
     }
}
```

And I test the result with the webTestClient in a integration test :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class TestErrorsIT {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    public void getErrors() {

        this.webTestClient.get().uri("/test/errors").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON).exchange().expectStatus()
                        .is5xxServerError();
    }
}
```

As a result, my test fails because my controller that returns an error flux returns a 200 status code instead of a 503 status code (the exception log "test" is well traced in my console). Do you know why ?

> java.lang.AssertionError: Range for response status value 200
>   expected: but was:
>
> > GET http://localhost:54432/test/errors
> >     WebTestClient-Request-Id: [1]
> >     Accept: [application/stream+json]
>
> No content
>
> < 200 OK < Content-Type: [application/stream+json] <
>   Transfer-Encoding: [chunked] < Date: [Fri, 03 Nov 2017 09:42:53 GMT]
>
> Content not available yet

Comment: Could you create a sample project illustrating this issue? I've tried to reproduce this copying/pasting your code but can't reproduce it.

Comment: Hello Brian, thanks for your answer. I create a simple project and don't reproduce the issue. After more analysis today, I find that "spring-cloud-starter-eureka" that we use in our project has "spring-boot-starter-web" as dependency and provides "spring-webmvc". After exclusion of "spring-boot-starter-web", all works fine.
Unfortunately, "spring-webmvc" is required for swagger (springfox) to work. So we have a working microservice but we lose swagger support...

Comment: Link for the springfox support of spring reactive : 
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1773

Comment: You should definitely add that as an answer to your question. This will be useful to other SO members!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, the application has a dependency on `spring-cloud-starter-eureka`, which itself has a transitive dependency on `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Adding `spring-boot-starter-web` to a Spring Boot application turns it into a Spring MVC application, which explains this behavior.